# How can we organize the repositories in a heirarchical structure in Azure devops? Is this Possible in GitHub or GitLab?

Tags: github, azure-devops, gitlab, azure-repos, azure-git-deployment

Im trying to organise the repositories in a heirarchical structure. Im trying to do it in Azure devops. But I found that the default structure is **Project/Repositories**.

[image: Heirarchical structure]

I need to have a repo structure as per the above image. Is there any way to do this?

Does GitHub or Gitlab support this kind of heirarchy?

Any Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

I tried creating a folder under a Project. But it is not possible.

We can only add multiple projects under it

Comment: GitLab does, with [groups and subgroups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/). GitHub repos are just a flat list, but you can set up [roles](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/roles-in-an-organization) and assign those to different repos to at least restrict read/push/admin/etc. permissions in some sort of hierarchy. I've never used Azure but I assume it has similar options for access and edit permissions.

Comment: Azure DevOps nor GitHub support adding drie structure to your repositories, naming conventions  are your best option here.

Comment: In GitHub you can create a structure of teams and link repositories to the specific teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has to do with what sense of a "hierarchy" do you want.

If you want the url structure of the repository to be hierarchical, **then gitlab will be the only solution**, as Zac mentioned, use gitlab's [subgroup feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/) to build the hierarchy you need.

For GitHub and Azure DevOps, they are similar, they don't have such feature.

But if you just want to manage the permission to access these repositories, then all of them can achieve.